# Rails 4 - server works in development mode, but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In development mode there are no problems, but when I launch the server in production mode it throws

```
undefined method `request_id' for #<ActionDispatch::Request
```

I recently downgraded from rails 5.1 to rails 4.2.7 because my polymorphic associations were not properly functioning.

I tried it both with puma and unicorn, so I don't think the problem is the server.

the full stack gist https://gist.github.com/itsgucci/c0fbc29d2122e648fd90cc5de418dce5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have logging with request id enabled in your `production.rb`, it will look something like this:

```
config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
```

You can comment it out and everything should just work.